# How to render openFrameworks app to host on browser

Tags: javascript, c++, openframeworks

I'm new to both openFrameworks and this compiler called Emscripten.
After struggling for a few days, I was able to compile my openFrameworks/C++ code into js but Emscripten gives me an html file with a lot of junk included (For example, there is a header and footer -
 http://openframeworks.cc/setup/emscripten/)

I'm trying to host the video/animation itself like it is on this page (http://www.syedrezaali.com/#/great-scott/) but I have no idea how to go about it. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you

Comment: Please share a code example, error messages, more info about your process and narrow the question down to a more specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow OF's guidelines Emscripten generates not only the html file but also some other files (I think it's 4 files in total). You need to copy all of those into your site, then link to the html file.

Notice that while developing you can use

`emrun --browser chrome bin/yourSample.html`

To open the file, but you cannot just open the .html file (not sure why). See [this guidelines](http://www.reginafloresmir.com/blog/2015/5/14/openframeworks-on-the-line) as well, which are linked in the OF tutorial.

### Update

I haven't tested this, but it looks like OF loads a site template. See [this makefile](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/63d20a5b5f3c4181f83febf2ad441921332f29e0/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/emscripten/config.emscripten.default.mk) for emscripten, you may specify your own via [PROJECT_EMSCRIPTEN_TEMPLATE](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/63d20a5b5f3c4181f83febf2ad441921332f29e0/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/emscripten/config.emscripten.default.mk#L88) or you could just change [the template](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/63d20a5b5f3c4181f83febf2ad441921332f29e0/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/emscripten/template.html) OF uses.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I have actually followed the tutorial you have linked and I was able to successfully compile to some html and js files. My concern here is that when I render the html with emrun (or on a server), there is the header (which gives you the option for fullscreen) and a footer that looks like some console. I do not want these, just the drawing by itself. Is this possible to make with emscripten? I want to replicate what's shown on this site: http://codedoodl.es

Comment: Hmm, after some reverse engineering I found this file: [openFrameworks/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/emscripten/template.html](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/19ec2688df9eecd818e333bef4753c302058de17/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/emscripten/template.html). I think you should be able to change it, or find where it's used, and choose a style of your choice for the generated canvas.